# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataset') in Laravel Jetstream-inertia

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

This error suddenly appears out of nowhere. i tried reinstalling the npm packages but it doesn't work. but when it works when i create a fresh project of jetstream-inertia with the same npm packages.
Any Help?
Tested on Chrome:

```
app.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataset')
    at exports.createInertiaApp (app.js:10)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:27154)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:53738)
    at app.js:53903
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (app.js:53775)
    at app.js:53905
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `defer` attribute to your script tag within the head tag like so :

```
<head>
  ........
 
  <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
```

Alternatively, you could add the script just below the `@inertia` tag in the scripts section excluding the `defer` attribute like so:

```
@inertia
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script> 
.......
</body>
```

Comment: A wonderful solution that helped me, thank you <3

Answer (score 2):

just put the script tag after @inertia tag in HTML. this error occurred because the script tag was in the head tag and vue couldn't find the #app element.
i believe you removed the "defer" attribute from the script tag. either add the defer attribute or load the app.js at the end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah could you elaborate on the answer